# How to echo mysql results to a text field

Tags: php, html, mysql

this script displays data from a specific email address which the user enters.

the snippet of code below displays the data in a textfield at the top of the page however I want to display the data in a textfield in the body of text.

```
echo '<input name="login" type="text" value="' . $result['name'] . '>';
```

What do  I change in the above code to enable me to do this.

```
<?php

$host=""; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name="orders"; // Table name  

$email = $_POST['textfield'];


        $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.
                          ';dbname='.$db_name.
                          ';charset=UTF-8',
                    $username, $password);
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `email`=:email LIMIT 1');
        $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
{
echo '<input name="login" type="text" value="' . $result['name'] . '>';
}
else
{
    echo "Email not found in the database!";
}


  ?>
```

form:

```
<form id="form_53" name="login" action="test.php">

   <input type="submit" value="Track">
   <input type="text" username="textfield" value="">
   <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $result['name']?>"> //I want to display results here

</form>
```

Comment: `echo '<input name="login" type="text" value="' . $result['name'] . '">';`

Comment: missing last `"` quote of the `value` attribute .. as @brbcoding pointed out ;)

Answer (score 2):

if both the code exists in the same file.. this will work

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $result['name']?>">
```

and if you want to check if there are rows returned you can use

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo ($stmt->rowCount()>0) ? $result['name'] : "" ?>">
```

> **edited the code so that you know what exactly you want to do**

First: Replace this code

```
if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
{
    echo '<input name="login" type="text" value="' . $result['name'] . '>';
}
else
{
    echo "Email not found in the database!";
}
```

just keep `$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and

```
 if($stmt->rowCount()<=0) echo "Email not found in the database!";
```

Second: now in HTML section

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo ($stmt->rowCount()>0) ? $result['name'] : "" ?>">
```

Comment: yes i know but it also displays it at the top of the page aswell. I only want it in the body

Comment: but i also want to echo 'Email not found in the database!' if it is wrong

Comment: thank you for help. One last thing, how would i display the 'Email not found in the database!' in the body?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't clobber `$result` you can do:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $result['name']; ?>"> //I want to display results here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<input name="login" type="text" value="' . $result['name'] . '">';
```

Just add a double quote to the `echo`'d string.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to accomplish. Of course make sure that the $results array is included in the session for the desired HTML page that you are working on.

```
<form id="form_53" name="login" action="test.php">

  <input type="submit" value="Track">
  <input type="text" username="textfield" value="">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $results['name']?>"> //I want to display results here

</form>
```